# Sql Server Building query from variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @String varchar(max),
        @Stat varchar(3),
        @Statval int


SET @Stat = 'STR'
SET @Statval = 500

set @String = 'UPDATE [Addpoints] SET ['+@stat+'] = ['+@stat+'] + '+@statval+''

SELECT @String
```

I'm trying to build query inside @String from some variables. But i'm getting error - 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UPDATE [Addpoints] SET ' to data type int.'

At the end i want @String to be like this

```
@String = 'Update [Addpoints] SET [STR] = [STR] + 500'
```

Comment: CAST(@statval AS VARCHAR) from here + '+@statval+''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast `int` values to `varchar` ones explicitly when you're combining them into string:

```
set @String = 'UPDATE [Addpoints] SET [' + @stat + '] = [' + @stat + '] + ' +
               cast(@statval as varchar(max))
```

Comment: And if your SQL Server is new enough, use [`concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your query would not be safe enough. Use this instead:

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @Stat VARCHAR(3) = 'STR'
    , @Statval INT = 500;

SET @String = N'
    UPDATE A
    SET A.' + QUOTENAME(@Stat) + N' += @Statval
    -- SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Addpoints AS A;';

PRINT @String;

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Statval INT', @Statval;
```

This query will generate following:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[STR] += @Statval
-- SELECT *
FROM dbo.Addpoints AS A;
```

Keep in mind that `[STR] = [STR] + 500` is exactly the same as `[STR] += @Statval`, it's just a nice shorthand.

As you can see column names are quoted. [QUOTENAME()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) does that for you and escapes illegal characters. And `sp_executesql` let's you create parameterized queries, which are safe and their execution plans are cached.

In your case @Statval will be assigned a value of 500.

Comment: This should be marked as answer since it address not just the op's requirement but also avoids sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

- Cast your statval to varchar as pointed by Andy
- or, If you have the ability, you can declare your statval directly as a  varchar